junit 5 runs specific cucumber feature twice
Running Cucumber with JUnit 5 works ok as long as all feature files are run.
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "src/main/features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com/nedap/healthcare/administration/cucumber/glue")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty, html:target/cucumber.html")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "long")
public class CucumberRunner {
}

But I you want to run just one feature
mvn compile test -Dcucumber.features=.../some.feature

Then that feature is executed, immediately followed by all features. This is best visible if print statements are placed in the before and after scenario hooks:
BeforeAll
Before
After
Before
After
AfterAll
[INFO] Running com.nedap.healthcare.administration.cucumber.CucumberRunner
BeforeAll

And then things start to go wrong, because the BeforeAll is not reentrant. (But that is not the problem, it should not be executed again.)
Interestingly the [INFO] line is not present before the first BeforeAll. It seems JUNit 5's Suite annotation is not working as it should.
Any suggestions what may be wrong?

A colleague found this https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2567
It turns out the root of the problem is JUnit 5 support in Maven and Gradle.
The workaround we chose are two different CucumberRunner classes. One annotated with Suite to run all feature files, one without to run a single feature.

You found a solution, but a better one was found a little after the issue was resolved.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#running-a-single-scenario-or-feature-from-the-cli

You should also not use @ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "src/main/features") but instead use JUnit Suites annotations for selecting tests @SelectDirectory("src/main/features").

Why is that second option better?

It uses JUnits API. So things like reruning failed scenarios also work (once you upgrade to 5.10.3). With cucumber.features Cucumber ignores anything JUnit asks. It's necessary to select a feature from the CLI with Maven, but that is the only use case.

Also, it gets rid of the big ass warning in your output. :D

With 5.10.3 (I was using 5.10.2) and the @SelectDirectories the -Dcucumber.features appears to have run fine. But the warning is still present, the tests are run twice, only the associated error does not seem to register. And the first run does not do any log-output. I'll wait for a decent fix.

Hm. My setup also doesn't do logging when running a single feature. Darn.

Did you use the full command I linked? mvn test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber -Dcucumber.plugin=pretty -Dcucumber.features=path/to/example.feature:10

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
